# How to send commands to my exe through the API

Tags: c#, api, console-application

I have a console application I've created. Here is the code:

```
[Guid("fa3ff58b-05a9-4c1a-85d0-f7bf0188ffbf")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("ConsoleWindow.Program")]
public class Program
{
    public Window myWindow = new Window();
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}

[Guid("fa3ff58b-05a9-4c1a-85d0-f7bf0188ffbf")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("ConsoleWindow.Window")]
public class Window
{
    public Window()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Console Window has been launched");
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for input...");
    }

    [DispId(1)]
    public void WriteToScreen(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

I then have a test project where I've referenced the EXE to expose the api
my test looks like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Program myProg = new Program();
        myProg.myWindow.WriteToScreen("example text to display");
    }
}
```

Everything builds okay but it doesn't seem to launch the exe when I run the test nor does it write to the window. Is there a way to get the exe to "launch" when I create an instance of it?

Apologies if i'm doing this completely wrong.

Comment: So its not an ideal solution but at the moment im resorting to using SendKeys

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do it completly wrong. If you directly want to start the exe, you have to use `Process.Start`. You can not do what you want to do. If you want to start an exe and write some thing to it's output (console), you have to start the exe as process and than connect to it. For example via TCP/IP, Namedpipes or something else.

The test is a single application with no console as you expect.

Here:

```
Program myProg = new Program();
        myProg.myWindow.WriteToScreen("example text to display");
```

You only create an instance of the **Programm** class, but it runs in your test.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean with app creating an instance of the Program class. The instance has been created and its referencing the Window class which has already been instantiated.

Comment: I understand regarding launching the EXE through Process.Start that makes sense. But really I wanted to then be able to send commands through the API rather than through pipes and tubes or any of the other gubbins.

Comment: Which api or window? Maybe i don't get what you want.

Comment: All I want is a way to send commands to my exe from another program, and write to the console window.

Comment: If you want to do this, you HAVE TO use Namedpipes or something else. Because you can not invoke the process as simple as you think.

Answer (score 0):

What exactlay are you trying to do?

If you want to start the application exe and get a console output you have to do:

```
public class Program
{
  public Window myWindow = new Window();
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Program myProg = new Program();
    myProg.myWindow.WriteToScreen("example text to display");
  }
}
```

If you want the unit test to check if the output worked try this question:

[Unit Test Help. How do I test for a message output to console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286518/unit-test-help-how-do-i-test-for-a-message-output-to-console)

After the discussion in the comments I propose this solution:

- Create a TestSuit for your tests <sup>[[1]](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=suite&r=2.6.2)</sup>
- use a TestFixtureSetUp to redirect the Console with `Console.SetOut` to write to a Window created for this purpose
- write to the Console inside the tests

<sub>Highly experimental ^_^ Also: if your automated tests need manual observation you might want to change how the tests work</sub>

Comment: I dont think ive explained it well. So basically I want my EXE to expose an API so that any of my C# projects can start up the EXE and write something to the window.
The reason for this is I have an SSH project that sends lots of commands and reads responses but doesnt display anything. A couple of the testers here have asked if I can get those responses to show in a console window or some other medium. I tried using Debug but they want this to be realtime and want to see the output as the code runs.

Comment: Why do you need an additional exe for this? If you have access to the code that sends the commands you could as well insert a method that outputs the commands to wherever you like

Comment: The code are C# unit tests so anything like Console.WriteLine wont show any output when those tests are being run by tools like MTM. So i figured I could create an exe that id launch and then write output to.